# Android Wear: Lock into watch face

Tags: java, android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I have written my own watch face app for Android wear devices and I wish to disable all other features of the watch to 'lock' the user into the watch face.

Is there any way to do this in my watch face app?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I don't want the user to able to do anything on the watch, make it _only_ a watch to them. No notifications, no settings, no interaction at all.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, the answer is no. Such a capability would be seriously detrimental to the UX of the device.